# How do I change Bleachbit's icon?

Tags: icons

Bleachbit is a really useful application and I use it daily. However, its icon is not the best, so I would like to change it. I really don't want to download a new icon theme, I'm happy with the default, I just want to change Bleachbit's icon. I've got the Faenza Bleachbit icon, that is what I'd like to use as a replacement.

How can I do this?

I'm just a user but I'm happy with terminal commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following:

1. Unlock the Bleachbit application for your unity launcher
2. Type in the terminal `sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/bleachbit.desktop`
3. Search for the label "Icon" *(at the end of the file)*

[image]

Edit the field to add the path to your new icon and save it.

*eg: Icon=/home/my/new/icon.png*

Then launch the application en lock it to the launcher with the new Icon.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks! I also changed the icon for Bleachbit (as root) by `gksu gedit /usr/share/applications/bleachbit-root.desktop`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a version older than [BleachBit version 0.9.3](http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/news/bleachbit-093), then upgrading to version 0.9.3 or later will give you a new application icon.

Comment: I have 0.9.1, the one in the Precise repo.